# I'm trying to learn Angular - why isn't my object not appearing using ng-repeat?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I wanted to be able to push an object into an array on a click event.  I was able to accomplish this.  However now my the the objects are not appearing in the ng-reapat for ordered.  What am I missing here?

```js
angular.module('app', []);

angular.module('app').controller("MainController", function() {
  var vm = this;
  vm.ordered = [];

  vm.menu = [{
    title: 'Pizza',
    type: 'entree',
    favorite: true,
    price: 10
  }, {
    title: 'Tacos',
    type: 'entree',
    favorite: false,
    price: 5
  }, {
    title: 'Onion Rings',
    type: 'app',
    favorite: false,
    price: 2
  }, {
    title: 'Ice Cream',
    type: 'dessert',
    favorite: false,
    price: 11
  }, {
    title: 'Mac n Cheese',
    type: 'app',
    favorite: false,
    price: 7
  }, {
    title: 'Salad',
    type: 'salad',
    favorite: true,
    price: 4
  }];
}).directive('section', function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    link: function(scope, element) {
      scope.ordered = [];
      element.bind('click', function(event) {
        scope.ordered.push(scope.item)
      });

    }
  };
});;
```

```css
.left {
  float: left;
  width: 50%;
}
.right {
  float: left;
  width: 50%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<body ng-app="app" ng-controller="MainController as main">

  <div class="left">
    <h2>Lists One</h2>
    <section id="{{item.id}}" ng-repeat="item in main.menu | filter:main.searchInput | orderBy:main.order.key:main.order.reverse">

      <strong>{{item.title}} </strong>
      <span>$ {{item.price}}</span>

    </section>
  </div>

  <div class="right">
    <h2>Lists Two</h2>
    <section id="{{item.id}}" ng-repeat="item in main.ordered | filter:main.searchInput | orderBy:main.order.key:main.order.reverse">

      <strong>{{item.title}} </strong>
      <span>$ {{item.price}}</span>

    </section>
  </div>
```

Comment: It looks like you have created a version of the `ordered` array that is local to your directive.

Comment: Is it possible to make this global?

Comment: It should be. What happens if you remove the `scope.ordered = []` from your directive? It should inherit it from the parent scope, no?

Comment: if I remove scope.ordered = [ ]  from the directive then the console tells me push is undefined

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned in your last question, you should use `ng-click` instead of a directive.

To simply add an item to the ordered list, you could do `ng-click="main.ordered.push(item)"` but you'd have problems with duplicate items in the ordered list when the user clicks an item multiple times.

Instead, you could add a function to your controller which would do things like check if it is in the ordered list, if it is add 1 to the quantity, increase the total price etc. Something like `ng-click="main.addToOrder(item)"`

```js
angular.module('app', []);

angular.module('app').controller("MainController", function() {
  var vm = this;
  vm.ordered = [];

  vm.menu = [{
    title: 'Pizza',
    type: 'entree',
    favorite: true,
    price: 10
  }, {
    title: 'Tacos',
    type: 'entree',
    favorite: false,
    price: 5
  }, {
    title: 'Onion Rings',
    type: 'app',
    favorite: false,
    price: 2
  }, {
    title: 'Ice Cream',
    type: 'dessert',
    favorite: false,
    price: 11
  }, {
    title: 'Mac n Cheese',
    type: 'app',
    favorite: false,
    price: 7
  }, {
    title: 'Salad',
    type: 'salad',
    favorite: true,
    price: 4
  }];
  
  vm.addToOrder = function(item) {
    if (vm.ordered.indexOf(item) > -1) { // if you modify the properties of ordered items (e.g. adding a quantity) you'll need to change this
      // increase quantity
      // increase total (if you have one)
      // etc.  
    } else {
      vm.ordered.push(item);  
    }
  };
});
```

```css
.left {
  float: left;
  width: 50%;
}
.right {
  float: left;
  width: 50%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<body ng-app="app" ng-controller="MainController as main">

  <div class="left">
    <h2>Lists One</h2>
    <section id="{{item.id}}" ng-repeat="item in main.menu | filter:main.searchInput | orderBy:main.order.key:main.order.reverse" ng-click="main.addToOrder(item)">

      <strong>{{item.title}} </strong>
      <span>$ {{item.price}}</span>

    </section>
  </div>

  <div class="right">
    <h2>Lists Two</h2>
    <section id="{{item.id}}" ng-repeat="item in main.ordered | filter:main.searchInput | orderBy:main.order.key:main.order.reverse">

      <strong>{{item.title}} </strong>
      <span>$ {{item.price}}</span>

    </section>
  </div>
```

Comment: Thanks for getting back with me. I really appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure that this has any connection to your error, but you should avoid directive names that can collide with HTML tag names.

Your `section` directive name here collides with the HTML5  tag.